# Fit line through 3D-vector and find intersection with plane

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, vector, 3d

I am trying to find a  way to fit a straight line through a known vector in the first step.
The second step should be to find the intersection between this line and the shown plane.
The vector I want to fit a line through is marked with the black ellipse and is named vector_3 in the code.

The goal is to adapt the length of vector_3 as the blue vector path rotates around the x- or y-axis to get a new vector which always ends at the plane.

Here is the code (reduced to what is relevant for now) and the resulting graph:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import 6D-Pose 
translation_6D_pose = np.array([100, 0, 0, 1])
rotation_6D_pose = np.array([0, 0, 0])

# Definition of vectors
origin = np.array([0, 0, 0])
vector_1 = np.array([0, 100, 10, 1])
vector_2 = np.array([-100, 0, 50, 1])
vector_3 = np.array([0, 100, 0, 1])
vector_4 = np.array([0, 0, 60, 1])

X, Y, Z = origin
U, V, W, _ = translation_6D_pose

A, B, C, _ = vector_1
D, E, F, _ = vector_2

G, H, I, _ = vector_3
J, K, L, _ = vector_4

# Plot figure:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
ax.set_xlim([-50, 200])
ax.set_ylim([-50, 200])
ax.set_zlim([-50, 200])

# Make plane:
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(-100, 100), range(0, 200))
z = xx*0 + 60
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.2)

# Plot vectors:
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W)
ax.quiver(U, V, W, A, B, C)
ax.quiver(U+A, V+B, W+C, D, E, F)
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, G, H, I, color="r")
ax.quiver(G, H, I, J, K, L, color="r")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot a line through your vector you can just create points that are aligned with the vector and plot them. To find the intersection, you can use the `intersection` function from sympy. Note that in your case you can also calculate it directly. Your plane is simply `z=60` so the calculation is pretty straightforward.

See code below for an example where I used sympy in order to make the answer more general:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import Point3D, Line3D, Plane


# Import 6D-Pose 
translation_6D_pose = np.array([100, 0, 0, 1])
rotation_6D_pose = np.array([0, 0, 0])

# Definition of vectors
origin = np.array([0, 0, 0])
vector_1 = np.array([0, 100, 10, 1])
vector_2 = np.array([-100, 0, 50, 1])
vector_3 = np.array([0, 100, 0, 1])
vector_4 = np.array([0, 0, 60, 1])

X, Y, Z = origin
U, V, W, _ = translation_6D_pose

A, B, C, _ = vector_1
D, E, F, _ = vector_2

G, H, I, _ = vector_3
J, K, L, _ = vector_4

# Plot figure:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
ax.set_xlim([-50, 200])
ax.set_ylim([-50, 200])
ax.set_zlim([-50, 200])

# Make plane:
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(range(-100, 100), range(0, 200))
z = xx*0 + 60
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z, alpha=0.2)

# Plot vectors:
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, U, V, W)
ax.quiver(U, V, W, A, B, C)
ax.quiver(U+A, V+B, W+C, D, E, F)
x=[U+A+k*D for k in range(10)]
y=[V+B+k*E for k in range(10)]
z=[W+C+k*F for k in range(10)]
ax.quiver(X, Y, Z, G, H, I, color="r")
ax.quiver(G, H, I, J, K, L, color="r")

#Computing intersection
plane = Plane(Point3D(0, 0, 60),(50,0,60),(0,50,60))
line = Line3D(Point3D(U+A, V+B, W+C), Point3D(U+A+10*D, V+B+10*E, W+C+10*F))
inter=plane.intersection(line)

#PLotting intersection
ax.scatter(float(inter[0][0]),float(inter[0][1]),float(inter[0][2]),color='tab:green',marker='x',s=100,label='intersection')

#PLotting line
ax.plot(x,y,z,label='line')


plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with the results, you can upvote the answer and mark the question as answered by ticking the green checkmark next to my answer. Thx!